# Git view/diff not working in Bug Genie

Tags: git, integration

Our git commits are showing just fine in the sidebar on tickets, but attempts to view/diff these files are going to a 404. Anyone have any ideas where I can start in fixing this?

I'm sure it's just a misconfiguration, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the actual reason this is happening is that we do not have gitweb setup!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instruction on how to set it up properly.

http://issues.thebuggenie.com/files/show/131

I assume you did not set up the `post-receive` properly or some other step on the way.

Comment: The commits are showing in the sidebar, so yes this has been done. The 404 just seems to happen when viewing or diffing the actual commits that are already showing up.